# iOS: In app purchase is not showing the common presentation

Tags: ios, storekit

Is my first time using the storekit to implement in app purchase.
And my test are going fine but I'm worried about the presentation.

My app is showing an alert like this:

[image]

But if I've checked other apps out there the presentation when user goes to pay is:

[image]

Why such a difference? is something wrong in my code?

```
let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the sandbox testing interface is very different from the end user experience. You just have to accept that if it works in the sandbox, it will work (with a different interface) for a real user.